# How do I get the position of the match in a FORMSOF INFLECTIONAL full-text search?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I'm using a CONTAINSTABLE query with MS SQL Server's full-text indexing engine to search within a textual column; e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
INNER MERGE JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(MyTable, sDescription, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "brains")')
    AS TBL1 ON TBL1.[key]=MyTable.ixKey
```

This does a great job of finding rows with a description including a word like "brains" (e.g. "brain", "brained"). However, when I display these results to the user, I'd like to highlight the word that matched their query (just like Google). But I can't just look for the search term in the results: if the result contains "brain", I obviously can't highlight "brains".

Can SQL Server tell me where in the column (either the word or character) the full-text match occurs? Alternatively, can I manually run the stemmer to get all the forms of the search term? I could highlight each of those individually, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 includes a function to get the inflected forms of a word or phrase, using the full-text engine's parser: [`sys.dm_fts_parser`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269(SQL.100).aspx#_Toc202506241).

```
SELECT display_term, source_term, occurrence FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "brains")', 1033, 0, 0)
```

gets a table like:

```
display_term | source_term | occurrence
---------------------------------------
brain        | brains      | 1
brains       | brains      | 1
brained      | brained     | 1
```

(Working with query phrases is a bit more work, as it inflects each word separately, but it's not too hard to put things back together.)

Now I can just highlight any occurrence of any of the inflected forms. It's a bit more work than if SQL Server just told me where the FTS matches are, but it'll do.

Answer (score 0):

The value in the result column `expansion_type` indicates this.
An expansion type of 2 is INFLECTIONAL, a 4 indicates thesaurus keyword expansion:

```
FORMSOF(THESAURUS, "Co")
source_term display_term    expansion_type
Co  co  0
Co  company 4

FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "Dog")
source_term display_term    expansion_type
Dog dog 0
Dog dogs    2
Dog dogged  2
Dog dogging 2

SQL

SELECT 
source_term,
display_term,
expansion_type
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser (FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "Dog"), 1033, 0, 0)
order by source_term, expansion_type
```